# What is the best way to create a multipage form in NativeScript Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm in the process of creating my first NativeScript Angular app and it consists of a form that will need to span across multiple screens. 
I tried to be creative and add the form pages into slides using  [TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides). This actually worked out beautifully as I was able to slide to each form page smoothly.

But a problem started to arise when initially navigating to the form component as it started to take a few seconds to load. I'm assuming this was happening because the form spans across 10 pages with multiple GridLayouts in each slide. I thought about using TabView but I wouldn't need the menu portion of it and I'm worried it will cause the same issue with loading speed.

So what is the best way to implement this?
Should I just create 10+ form components, use a universal service and just route each form part to another or is there a better way to "encapsulate" this into one component without any performance loss?

I also saw in the NativeScript documentation about this..

> It is possible to nest `<router-outlet>` component inside `<page-router-outlet>` or another
>   `<router-outlet>`

But there isn't any documentation on how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many way to use nested router-outlet in ns, and in a very big project, it is best to use shared modules architecture, which enable a module nested in another, so the view can be nested too.

Here is my nativescript sample with nested  using shared modules architecture :

in profile is nested in app.component.

in parent view: 
https://github.com/Arthurisme/auth0-iosmorphic/blob/master/Mobile/Nativescript-for-Spring-Auth0/app/app.component.ts

in childview:
https://github.com/Arthurisme/auth0-iosmorphic/blob/master/Mobile/Nativescript-for-Spring-Auth0/app/profile/profile.component.html

Comment: Thank for you for your response. I think until someone suggests a better option, nested routing would work best but I can't seem to be get it working.. I get an error when I nest routes. 

`{ path: "form", component: FormComponent,
       children: [
         { path:"outcome", component: OutcomeComponent, outlet: "addhand"},
         { path: "endon", component: EndonComponent, outlet: "addhand"}
       ]
    }`

This gives me an error... in promise Error: Cannot match any routes: 'form'

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working. I had to remove the `outlet:"addhand"` and it works. I'm gonna go with this until I learn any other way. Thanks again!